# Проблема с cogs, не могу понять в чем проблема

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Доброй ночи, структурировал код с помощью когов(cogs) перестала работать единственная команда help остальные работают нормально, не могу понять в чём проблема, вот сам код

```
@commands.command(aliases = ["hel","Информация"])
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def help(self, ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    emb = discord.Embed (title = 'Навигация по командам :clipboard:', colour = discord.Color.gold())
    emb.add_field(name ='Описание сервера :pencil:', value = 'Rojers Squad, правила можно прочитать в канале #правила')
    emb.add_field(name ='{}clear :broom:'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Очистка чата')
    emb.add_field(name ='{}voteban :lock:'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Бан участника')
    emb.add_field(name ='{}kick :wave:'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Кик с сервера')
    emb.add_field(name ='{}unban :unlock:'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Разбан участника')
    emb.add_field(name ='{}tempmute :mute:'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Мут участника')
    emb.add_field(name ='{}unmute :speaker:'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Размут участника')
    emb.add_field(name ='{}ds :rose:'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Ссылка на наш дс')
    emb.add_field(name ='{}slot '.format(PREFIX), value = 'Игра для развлечения')


    await ctx.send (embed = emb, delete_after=30)




class User(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client



    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Запущен бот!')
        await self.client.change_presence (status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game('!tiktok | !help'))


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        pass




def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(User(client))
```

Comment: А ошибки? А весь код там где вы объявляете клас?

Comment: Ошибок нету, после удаление самой команды не отправляется ембед

Comment: Добавил объявление класса в суть вопроса

Comment: @xZartsust выше